# How to make the command multi-line?

Tags: command-line, quoting, thunderbird

The following command:

```
thunderbird -compose to=abc@example.com,subject=testmail,body="something"
```

works, but only if it has no comma in the body tag. It works with:

```
"dsafdsafcc \/sda/fads ;.f af af a"
```

But it won't work if instead of a `;` a put a `,` . Alternatives, like `\,` also don't work. The `,` seems to break any string that I pass to `body`.

How can I pass a complete text to `body`, with `,,` and new lines?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap the contents of the `body="' ...something...'"` to get what you want:

```
$ thunderbird –compose "to='foo@bar.com',subject='nice tip',body='Check out this neat command line tip'"
```

You can also put the contents of the body in a file and send it like this:

```
$ thunderbird –compose "to='foo@bar.com',subject='nice tip',body='$(cat somefile.txt)'"
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. But      thunderbird -compose to=abc@example.com,subject=testmail,"body='dsafdsafcc\, \/sda/fads ,.f af af a'" (wrapped body tag), works!

Comment: @FrançoisPerenot - I think you can put the body in a file and do this: `...,body='$(cat somefile.txt)'"`.

Comment: @FrançoisPerenot - so just the `,,` doesn't work? What's left to your question?

Comment: Everything works now, ',,' when I do what I say in the first comment, multiline, when I save to a file and use a variable to load it.

Comment: @FrançoisPerenot - if this resolves your issue can you please mark this answer as accepted so others know that your issue has been resolved. Thanks.